# Is Cisco Misquoting the Nexus 7000 specs

Tags: networking, cisco, local-area-network, switch, cisco-nexus

Looking at the following image:

http://blogs.cisco.com/wp-content/uploads/7000-family-550x358.png

Cisco is quoting the 7009 as having a 10GigE density of 336 and a backplane bandwidth of 550G/slot.  The only way to get 550Gig/Slot is to have 5 FAB modules, taking up five slots.  There is no possible way to get 336 10GigE (7 slot * 48 port/slot) since the switch must have FAB modules.

I am asking this because I am specing out switches and can not see the purpose of purchasing a 7009 since this switch takes double the RU and contains the same amount of IO slots as the 7004.  It contains the same amount of IO slots as the 7004 because 5 of the 7 remaining IO slots must be used on FAB modules to get the same performance as the lower end 7004.  The 7004 has built in FAB modules and also takes only two IO slots.

Answer (score 4):

FAB modules go in the front center of the chassis on the 7009.  If you go to Cisco's website they have a 3D model where you can click on 'Fabric Module' and it shows you exactly where it is. Or you can just follow this direct link: http://www.cisco.com/assets/swa/vid/nexus7009_kaon/index.html.

Cisco does not count fabric modules against the I/O module count.

Since this is your third or fourth question about Nexus 7K's, I strongly recommend you find a VAR (value-added reseller) to work with while specifying this purchase.